# Show metatags on node add/edit pages on custom theme

Tags: meta-tags

I have a user role which can add/edit metatags (Metatag module) and when I allow overlay and admin theme access for that user role - everything is OK. But if they are editing/adding node from my custom theme for some reason they cannot see fields for metatags, only tab with the label "Meta tags". Same thing is with the URL alias, only tab. I'm not sure what can be the cause or am I missing something.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was related to Bootstrap custom theme and vertical tabs. So fields where only hidden in my theme and it was a style issue. Nothing to do with privileges.